# Nested JSON Format

Tags: json

I have a data Called 'Village'.

```
Country:
         {
            State:{
                    District:{
                                Taluk:{
                                           Village: String
                                       }
                              }
                   }
         }
```

Is this correct JSON format for Data "Village".

Comment: You need to wrap your keys with `"` (e.g. `"Country"`) , except for that, I have nothing else to say about the format.

Comment: Use a validator. There's plenty online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about validating JSON, which is work more suitable for machines, as opposed to fellow humans on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the modified json to make it valid

```
 {
"Country": {
    "State": {
        "District": {
            "Taluk": {
                "Village": "String"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and to validate any json string use http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare types such as String in JSON. Also, you need to quote your variable names. It seems like your declaring a structure in JSON. I would replace String with an empty string, that is essentially declaring the type:

```
{"Country":
         {
            "State":{
                    "District":{
                                "Taluk":{
                                           "Village": ""
                                       }
                              }
                   }
         }
}
```